# How to scrape football week results

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to get the results of a virtual football league and arrange them according to the weeks as shown in this [excel file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQ-RXODO0N39YSCLWncqnfRgnxGri31yAzw7fD0xv3Rglx7P5jzgbxmBd7zXyQZjLPFIIvUZ1CprOkG/pubhtml), am trying to scrape the results from this site https://odibets.com/league?br=1&tab=results and below is the python code have written so far

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import pandas as pd

page = requests.get('https://odibets.com/league?br=1&tab=results')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find(class_="l-league-table-results" )

results = table.find_all(class_='results')
for i in results:
        weeks = i.find(class_='results-title').getText()
        week = weeks[55:58]
        

        day = i.find_all(class_='results-body')[3]
        home = day.find_all('td')[0].getText()
        away = day.find_all('td')[2].getText()
        score = day.find_all('td')[1].getText()
        homeScore = score[:1]
        awayScore = score[1:]
        print(awayScore)
```

How can i write the code to achieve the same results as shown in the [excel file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQ-RXODO0N39YSCLWncqnfRgnxGri31yAzw7fD0xv3Rglx7P5jzgbxmBd7zXyQZjLPFIIvUZ1CprOkG/pubhtml)

Comment: I've got Access Denied clicking on the excel file link. Can you make it public?

Comment: @AndrejKesely have already changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will print week, teams and scores:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://odibets.com/league?br=1&tab=results'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

print('{:<5}{:<25}{:<25}{:<12}{:<12}'.format('WEEK', 'HOME', 'AWAY', 'HOME SCORE', 'AWAY SCORE'))
for row in soup.select('tr.results-body'):
    week = row.find_previous('td', colspan="3").text.split()[3]
    home_team, home_score, away_score, away_team = row.get_text(strip=True, separator='|').split('|')
    print('{:<5}{:<25}{:<25}{:<12}{:<12}'.format(week, home_team, away_team, home_score, away_score))
```

Prints:

```
WEEK HOME                     AWAY                     HOME SCORE  AWAY SCORE  
34   NORWICH                  Burnley                  1           1           
34   Manchester Reds          Wolves                   2           2           
34   SHEFFIELD U              Liverpool                0           1           
34   ASTON V                  Brighton                 1           2           
34   London Reds              Leicester                2           3           
34   Tottenham                Bournemouth              0           0           
34   Newcastle                Manchester Blue          1           4           
34   Southampton              Palace                   2           0           
34   West Ham                 Watford                  0           0           
34   London Blues             Everton                  3           1           
33   Bournemouth              NORWICH                  1           0           
33   Watford                  London Blues             0           0           
33   Wolves                   ASTON V                  4           0           
33   Burnley                  SHEFFIELD U              2           1           
33   Palace                   London Reds              0           1           
33   Brighton                 West Ham                 0           0           
33   Manchester Reds          Tottenham                1           4           
33   Everton                  Newcastle                2           1           
33   Leicester                Manchester Blue          1           3           
33   Liverpool                Southampton              1           0           
32   Southampton              Burnley                  3           2           
32   West Ham                 Wolves                   0           2           
32   London Blues             Brighton                 0           2           
32   Tottenham                NORWICH                  1           0           

...and so on.
```